# Akka ActorSystem never terminate in Java

Tags: java, java-8, akka, digital-signature, akka-actor

Im using Akka 2.5.6 in Java 8 and I want to know the right way to finish de ActorSystem, part of the functionality of my code is to process some XML files and validate them, to achieve this I have created 3 actors:
Controller, Processor and Validator.
The Controller is responsible for initiating the process and sending file by file and other information to the Processor, then the Processor create a digital signature of the file and sends the response to the Validator that finally validates the status and sends an OK message to the Controller which is counting the number of files validated and compares them with the total files. Once the total of files with the total of validated files are equal, I call to finish the ActorSystem with the terminate () method.

The method to finish is as follows:

```
     private void endActors() 
      {         
     ActorSystem actorSystem = getContext().system();
     Future <Terminated> terminated = actorSystem.terminate();
      do {
           log.info ("Waiting to finish ...");
           try {
           Thread.sleep (30000L);
           } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
             log.error ("Error in Thread.");
           }
         } while (! ended.isCompleted ());
             log.info ("Actors finished processing.");
       }
```

The loop never ends because the future is never complete, I dont know if this is the right way, I hope you have understood me and can help me or give me some advice.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following (the key here is the on complete) . I wrote a class along these lines to use in a setup and teardown for junit, to avoid issues from actor system not fully terminating in the teardown of one test before being created in another test.  (that caused port already in use issues)

```
private static ActorSystem system = null;    
private static Future<Terminated> terminatedFuture;

public static ActorSystem getFreshActorSystem() {
    tearDownActorSystem();
    while(system != null) {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(500L);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {

        }
    }
    system  = ActorSystem.create();
    return system;
}

public static void tearDownActorSystem() {
    if (system !=null && !isInMiddleOfTerminating()) {
        terminatedFuture = system.terminate();

        terminatedFuture.onComplete( new OnComplete(){
            @Override
            public void onComplete(Throwable failure, Object success) throws Throwable {
                system = null;
                terminatedFuture = null;
            }
        } , system.dispatcher());
    }
}

private static boolean isInMiddleOfTerminating() {
    return terminatedFuture !=null;
}
```